# Angular 4+ , ag-grid: Unit test angular component that implements AgRendererComponent

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ag-grid, angular-components

I have a angular component that implements AgRendererComponent for one of the columns in ag-grid.

I want to write unit tests for the component below. Could someone guide me through. This might look to be a very simple component but i may add more logic later on.
I use ag-grid - 13.0.0 and angular - 4.4+

*Ignore if there are any syntax errors.*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-column',
  template: `<span class="hyperlink"><a href="#">{{ columnValue }}</a></span>`
})

export class GridColumnComponent implements AgRendererComponent  {

 private params: any;
 columnValue: string;

 constructor() { }

 refresh(params: any) {
    this.params = params;
 }
 agInit(params:any):void {
    this.params = params;
    this.columnValue = this.params.node.data.columnValue;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing this component shouldn't make no difference as testing any other, even if it implements the AgRendererComponent.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GridColumnComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
//this might be the only tricky part, where to initialize the params object of Aggrid
    component.agInit({
      context: TestBed.createComponent(YourParentComponent).componentInstance,
      data: { otherdata :"tomock"},
      node: { data : "moreDataToMock"}

    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```